# Boolean Algebra Simplification - In sum of products form

Tags: boolean-algebra

How would you simplify this expression? I've been struggling with it for a while, but seem not to be getting anywhere near the right answer.

Y = (A' + BD + C'D)' (B'CD')

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I HOPE YOU KNOW THE FORMULAS OF INVERSE ETC
$$
Y = ( (A'+ C'D) + BD )'.(B'CD')
$$
$$
\to (A CD').(B' + D' ).(B'CD')  
$$
$$
\to (AB'CD').(B'+D')
$$
$$
\to AB'CD'
$$
formulas used :

$1st line$ : $(x +y)' =x'.y'$

$  2ndline$: $x.x =x$

$3rdline$ : open the bracket